# ffmpeg: function to load an image

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I've tried to load an image file using `ff_load_image` function defined in img2dec.c:

```
  char* filename = argv[1];
  uint8_t* data;
  int linesize, width, height, log_ctx;
  enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;

  //load the image
  int i = ff_load_image(&data, &linesize, &width, &height, &pix_fmt, filename, &log_ctx);
  printf("%i\n", i);
```

However, I'm getting a segmentation fault for no reason. I've placed `printf` statements all over `ff_load_image`, and it's reaching to the end of the function. Why would I get segmentation fault? And is there a better way to load an image? I would like to get every pixel in the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you're passing incorrect arguments. According to the [`ff_load_image` documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/1.1/lavfutils_8c.html), your arguments should be:

1. uint8_t *[4]
2. int [4]
3. int *
4. int *
5. enum AVPixelFormat *
6. const char *
7. void *

Your first two arguments seem to be incorrect.

- Your first argument is `uint8_t **` which would still be okay if you allocated memory for at least 4 `uint8_t` pointers, but `data` is not pointing to valid memory.
- Your second argument is `int *` which has the same problem of not pointing to valid memory.

So, your program is probably invoking undefined behavior.

I would change your initialization to:

```
uint8_t *data[4];
int linesize[4];
```

and then call `ff_load_image` as:

```
int i = ff_load_image(data, linesize, &width, &height, &pix_fmt,
                      filename, &log_ctx);
```

Additionally, you may want to check out [an example of how to use `ff_load_image`](https://github.com/jnicklas/ffmpeg_test/blob/master/test.c).

Comment: You are right. That was why I got segmentation fault. Thank you.